# Installing Ubuntu 12.04LTS on WD Hard-drive: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr Missing Error?

Tags: wubi

I've tried installing Ubuntu on my 1TB WD Hard-Drive. I've done this using EasyBCD, and on a Windows 7 PC. Problem is, after restarting my PC (and booting from the G:\ hard-drive), I get this error:

```
\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
```

I checked the `G:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr` and the file exists.

[image]

I've searched around for hours and the problem still persists. I can't understand what the solution is.

How to fix this?

P.S. I'm a beginner in Ubuntu, though I have used it as a production server and desktop environment for a week.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my wubuldr.mbr folder: http://gyazo.com/755dc0f5e45c3642a53fed48cc6b3030

Comment: I have installed a dual boot before, however would like Ubuntu on a hard-drive for portibility. The question has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi boots via the Windows host OS's boot manager (using `grub4dos`). It doesn't install it's own bootloader so it can't boot independently. Therefore booting from the external drive won't do anything.

Wubi is not portable either (maybe with some manual effort, but not in a practical way).

So if you want a portable install on an external drive, you need to do a proper install. That will be fully portable (assuming you don't need custom graphics drivers on one computer, but not the other).